# Sharing internet to multiple LAN connections

Tags: windows, networking, ics

I am running windows 8.1

My problem is I have 4 LAN ports, out of them 1 is for the internet and other 3 connect separate hub/switch specifically. I want to use that 1 internet connection with other 3 LAN connections.
I tried Internet sharing, but by it, I can only share connection to 1 LAN adapter.

I can select all adapters and chose bridge, but that's disabling some adapters automatically and not succeeding.

I want it to be working as a router, which accepts one WAN input and output many other network connections to use internet.

Comment: How many devices do you want to connect via this PC? What is stopping you using a single connector with a switch? This is very much NOT what Microsoft want you to use a desktop OS for, if you really want to do this, Linux would be a much better choice.

Comment: hi julian
i have 3 other computers which i want to connect to my main computer without any router or switch in between,so that i can give full speed to them.

Comment: I don't think it will work that way even if you do manage to get all the ports working. PC's are not designed as switches and you would be making your PC work hard to route all those packets as well as doing all the desktop stuff. In any case, your Internet connection is likely to be far slower than an single PC port so it is not relevant.